# Using Python Pickle Object In Java

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, pickle, jython

I have a `pickle object` for [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in `Python`. I want to use this object in Java to make predictions. Is that possible? As I see, a `Python pickle object` can be used in `Java` in [that](https://nikoskatsanos.com/blog/2017/01/08/python-unpickling-in-java/) way but I'm not sure if it works for a machine learning model.

Edit: I figured out that Pickle is just a "serialized object", which was non-sense to think to use in Java. I had to use the Java classifier implementation from [DronovIlya](https://github.com/DronovIlya/random-forest-java) instead of using Python object in Java.

Comment: I'm skeptical that Jython will work with an `sklearn` model object, which will depend on things like `numpy` and `scipy`. Can your Java process just use a Python process?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with _your Java process just use a Python process_, do you mean something such as using the Python script(or process) in Java code?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** NO.

**Long answer:**

According to python documentation:

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,” 1 or “flattening”; however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here are “pickling” and “unpickling”

This means that the given byte stream is only syntactically valid in Python only unless you want to write an object transpiler.

You are approaching your problem in the wrong way. ML model is just a set of coefficients/parameters that you have optimized to get a close approximation of your target variable. You should be able to take that set of coefficients/parameters and use it in any language.

Comment: I had implemented a ML model in Java too, but I was thinking about passing the model from Python in a system like Apache NiFi or Apache Spark system such that a Java program could use the Python model since Scikit-learn models have more parameters than the ordinary ones. At the end, I couldn't use Scikit-learn anyway.

Comment: @büşraçelik Pickle is NOT the model. It is serialised Python class.  Your model is actually represented by coefficients that your algorithm generated while learning from training data. For example: For a simple regression model represented by y = mx + c, the model is not the object of LinearRegression class but the value of m and c itself.

Comment: @büşraçelik For a Random Forest implementation, your model is the tree structure representing your nodes and gini value given to that node.

Comment: Can you share the approach you used. My team is facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

We can use cPickle class from jython

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/org/python/modules/cPickle.html

Comment: Cpickle can be used for objects from classes to serialize but how can you import the sci-kit learn library properties? Can you give the  Let's say you build a model with parameters and you trained the model but how can you use the model for testing in Java?